# findMeetingTime not returning suggestions as expected

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to book a meeting with someone in Geneva, while I am working from Eastern Standard Time.   Our working hours overlap from 8am to 12pm and on 2018-05-25 we have a free slot from 8am to 9am.

I created an all day `TimeContraint` and set the `ActivityDomain` to the 'work' restriction:

```
"timeConstraint": {
  "activityDomain":"work", 
  "timeslots": [ 
  { 
    "start": { 
      "dateTime": "2018-05-25T00:00:00",  
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time" 
    },  
    "end": { 
      "dateTime": "2018-05-26T00:00:00",  
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time" 
    } 
  } 
]},
```

Using this TimeConstraint, when searching for an hour long meeting with findMeetingTimes, I got no results.   Empty Reason of AttendeesUnavailable.

I ran the exact same search with a TimeContraint that was my actual working hours instead of all day:

```
"timeConstraint": {
"activityDomain":"work", 
"timeslots": [ 
  { 
    "start": { 
      "dateTime": "2018-05-25T08:00:00",  
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time" 
    },  
    "end": { 
      "dateTime": "2018-05-25T17:00:00",  
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time" 
    } 
  } 
]},
```

This returned the single expected Meeting Suggestion from 8am to 9am.

What is the correct way to use findMeetingTime?   I have been creating a `TimeConstraint` with a single `timeslots` that could potentially span months.  I have been assuming the `ActivityDomain` would handle only returning `MeetingSuggestions` during working hours.  However, in this example I got no results when my timeslot spanned the full day and only got the result I expected when I manually set the timeslot to my working hours.

Anyone else experiencing this?

**Additional Info that further makes me think this is a graph issue**

When I use the `TimeConstraint` of the full day and change the meeting duration to 30 minutes.  I actually get the expected two results of `8:00am to 8:30am` and `8:30am to 9:00am`.

```
"timeConstraint": {
"timeslots": [
  {
    "start": {
      "dateTime": "2018-05-25T00:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
      "dateTime": "2018-05-26T00:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    }
  }
]},
"meetingDuration": "PT30M"
}
```

*Gave me the following results (removed unimportant parts)*

```
"meetingTimeSuggestions": [
    {
        "meetingTimeSlot": {
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2018-05-25T12:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2018-05-25T12:30:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        },
    },
    {
        "meetingTimeSlot": {
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2018-05-25T12:30:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2018-05-25T13:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
```